# not UTF-8 files + java + UTF-8 database

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

My website has plain text upload functionality. Users can upload different encoded files. I need to make some preprocessing but finally I want to save content from those files to the UTF-8 encoded text column on my database.

I know that Java is really user-unfriendly in such cases, but what is the best approach to implement it?

Comment: Does the user specify the encoding when they upload it, or are you meant to guess?

Comment: no, my users are without IT knowledge

Comment: Okay, so you should be looking for heuristic encoding detection algorithms. The rest is pretty easy - Java isn't "really user-unfriendly" about encodings.

Comment: it would be friendly, if it had a method: String convert(text, "UTF-8") and heuristic encoding detection algorithm lied in the guts.

Comment: @smash: that wouldn't even make sense, as strings in Java are *always* sequences of utf-16 code units. There's no such thing as a utf-8 string in Java.

Comment: Maybe it stands in contradictions in low level Java details. As I said Java is "user unfriendly" in it. 
Look at Java data/time APIs - are nightmares, this is why we use  Joda time library. Developers should don't care about Java low level inside, we have to realize business cases

Comment: Understanding what a String is isn't "low level" - understanding the meaning of a string is a fundamental part of the platform. Yes, it could be nice for Java to have a heuristic encoding detection class as part of the standard library, but it's not a big deal. This is nothing like the date/time situation, IMO.

Comment: the truth is that I don't care if "strings in Java are always sequences of utf-16 " till I'll have ??????? on my output.

Comment: If you don't care about the fundamentals of the platform you're running on (and this is a really important basic point you should know about) you're always going to fail. Have fun with binary floating point...

Answer (score 0):

If you website is hosted on a *nix machine, your best bet is to run the `file` utility on whatever your users upload. It will give you a best guess at the encoding. You can then use that to have `recode` turn whatever format you found into UTF-8.
This is highly error prone, because guessing the types can fail, especially if the text is short, but this is the best you can do.